# Rolling a random die twice python

Tags: python, random

I need to run a random 6 sided dice twice and return the sum of them.  I am not sure if this is right but I don't think it is, I am still learning python so I am pretty new when it comes to this kind of stuff.

```
import random

def roll_die():
    roll1 = random.randint(1,6)
    roll2 = random.randint(1,6)
    total = roll1 + roll2

    return total
```

Comment: @wiso, missed the `def roll_die` line?

Comment: What leads you to believe that it is not correct, and have you tested your assumption?

Comment: Looks good to me. Tip: rename the function roll_die() to roll_dice().

Comment: For some reason I thought it was incorrect the first time I tested it, it gave me an error but I changed a line and it works, thanks guys and sorry for the waste of time :P

Comment: @Shmoe, it may have been a basic question, but it was clear and well written and may be of help to someone down the road, so it's not a waste of time. Just make sure you accept an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works.

It is also best practice to initialize the random generator by calling:

```
random.seed()
```

at the beginning of your script, even if it is not necessary, and it is not a mistake to omit it.

If you want to test it, add the following:

```
print(roll_die())
```

at the end of the script, to print the result, since the *return* keyword does not print anything on the screen, it is only used to let the result of the function out.

Comment: I disagree that explicitly calling random.seed() is good practice, unless needed.

Comment: It is bad practice only if you call it everytime you need a random.

Comment: I didn't say it was bad practice.  I said it wasn't good practice.  What I'm saying is in the original question there is no call to random.seed and that is just fine.  If someone wants to add a no-args call to random.seed() it's not wrong, it's just extra code.

Comment: Sorry then, I misunderstood. Well, in such a small script it is not useful, I agree. It has little or no effect at all (depending on environment timing factors) when called at program start, but it is very useful to call seed() at the beginning of a function when stronger randomization effect is needed, since the vast majority of the system random functions use pseudo-random generator algorithms which can bring redundancy (even better if called with a different seed than the timestamp). When I was new to this, I spent weeks trying to understand the redundancy I found in this type of randoms.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your function after that: `print roll_die()`

Answer (score 0):

This will do exactly what you want. For more info, use `help(something)` in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> import random
>>> help(random.randint)
Help on method randint in module random:

randint(self, a, b) method of random.Random instance
    Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.
```

You can also test this in a brute-force fashion:

```
>>> valid_numbers = list(range(2, 13)) # You can just use range(2, 13) in python 2.x
>>> valid_numbers
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> while len(valid_numbers) > 0:
...     roll = roll_die()
...     if roll in valid_numbers:
...         print(roll)
...         valid_numbers.remove(roll)
...
4
10
5
7
6
8
11
9
3
2
12
```

Of course, your entries should be different than mine.